# Slider JS cannot work at IE9 and older versions

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this page http://kreditmoney.ch/de/kreditantrag/index.php

Slider at right side can not work at IE9 and older version. I fixed error at IE11.

**I assume that, the error is in this code:**
.........

```
else {  
            this.fireEvent('onChange', this.step);
            this.bkg.style.clip = "rect(0px "+  (parseInt(this.drag.value.now[this.z]) +3)  + "px 10px 0px)"
```

........

**This is full code:**

```
    var SliderMoj = new Class({
options: {
    onChange: Class.empty,
    onComplete: Class.empty,
    onTick: function(pos){
        this.moveKnob.setStyle(this.p, pos);            
    },
    start: 0,
    end: 100,
    offset: 0,
    knobheight: 20,
    knobwidth: 14,
    mode: 'horizontal',
    clip_w:0, 
    clip_l:0,
    isinit:true,
    snap: false,
    range: false,
    numsteps:null
},
initialize: function(el, knob,bkg, options, maxknob) {
    this.setOptions(options);
    this.element = $(el);
    this.knob = $(knob);
    this.previousChange = this.previousEnd = this.step = -1;
    this.bkg = $(bkg);
    if(this.options.steps==null){
        this.options.steps = this.options.end - this.options.start;
    }
    if(maxknob!=null)
        this.maxknob = $(maxknob);
    //else
    //  this.element.addEvent('mousedown',         this.clickedElement.bindWithEvent(this));
    var mod, offset;
    switch(this.options.mode){
        case 'horizontal':
            this.z = 'x';
            this.p = 'left';
            mod = {'x': 'left', 'y': false};
            offset = 'offsetWidth';
            break;
        case 'vertical':
            this.z = 'y';
            this.p = 'top';
            mod = {'x': false, 'y': 'top'};
            offset = 'offsetHeight';
    }
    this.max = this.element[offset] - this.knob[offset] + (this.options.offset * 2);
    this.half = this.knob[offset]/2;
    this.full = this.element[offset] - this.knob[offset] + (this.options.offset * 2);
    this.min = $chk(this.options.range[0]) ? this.options.range[0] : 0;
    this.getPos = this.element['get' + this.p.capitalize()].bind(this.element);
    this.knob.setStyle('position', 'relative').setStyle(this.p, - this.options.offset);

    this.range = this.max - this.min;
    this.steps = this.options.steps || this.full;
    this.stepSize = Math.abs(this.range) / this.steps;
    this.stepWidth = this.stepSize * this.full / Math.abs(this.range) ;


    if(maxknob != null) {
        this.maxPreviousChange = -1;
        this.maxPreviousEnd = -1;
        this.maxstep = this.options.end;
        this.maxknob.setStyle('position', 'relative').setStyle(this.p, + this.max - this.options.offset).setStyle('bottom', this.options.knobheight);
    }
    var lim = {};
    //status = this.z
    lim[this.z] = [- this.options.offset, this.max - this.options.offset];
    //lim[this.z] = [100, this.max - this.options.offset];

    this.drag = new Drag(this.knob, {
        limit: lim,
        modifiers: mod,
        snap: 0,
        onStart: function(){
                this.draggedKnob();
        }.bind(this),
        onDrag: function(){
                this.draggedKnob();
        }.bind(this),
        onComplete: function(){
                this.draggedKnob();
                this.end();
        }.bind(this)
    });
    if(maxknob != null) {  
        this.maxdrag = new Drag(this.maxknob, {
            limit: lim,
            modifiers: mod,
            snap: 0, 
            onStart: function(){
                this.draggedKnob(1);
            }.bind(this),
            onDrag: function(){
                this.draggedKnob(1);
            }.bind(this),
            onComplete: function(){
                this.draggedKnob(1);
                this.end();
            }.bind(this)
        });     
    }

    if (this.options.snap) {
        //this.drag.options.grid = Math.ceil(this.stepWidth);
        this.drag.options.grid = (this.full)/this.options.numsteps ;
        this.drag.options.limit[this.z][1] = this.full;
        //this.drag.options.grid = this.drag.options.grid - (this.knob[offset]/this.options.numsteps);
        status = "GRID - " + this.drag.options.grid  + "  , full = " + this.full// DEBUG

    }
    if (this.options.initialize) this.options.initialize.call(this);
},
setMin: function(stepMin){
    this.step = stepMin.limit(this.options.start, this.options.end);
    this.checkStep();
    this.end();
    this.moveKnob = this.knob;
    this.bkg.style.clip = "rect(0px "+  (parseInt(this.toPosition(this.step)) +3) + "px 10px 0px)";
    status =this.bkg.style.clip + "  vl= " + parseInt(this.toPosition(this.step)) ; //Debug
    this.fireEvent('onTick', this.toPosition(this.step));
    return this;
},
setMax: function(stepMax){
    this.maxstep = stepMax.limit(this.options.start, this.options.end);
    this.checkStep(1);
    this.end();
    this.moveKnob = this.maxknob;
    var w= Math.abs(this.toPosition(this.step)- this.toPosition(this.maxstep)) + 3 ;
    var r = parseInt(this.clip_l + w); 
    this.bkg.style.clip = "rect(0px "+  r + "px 10px "+ this.clip_l + "px)";

    this.fireEvent('onTick', this.toPosition(this.maxstep));
    // For Init Only 
    if(this.options.isinit){
        var lim = {}; var mi,mx;
        mi = - this.options.offset; 
        mx= parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left')) - this.options.offset-4 ;
        lim[this.z] = [mi, mx];
        this.drag.options.limit = lim;
        this.options.isinit = false;
    }
    return this; 
},
clickedElement: function(event){
    var position = event.page[this.z] - this.getPos() - this.half;
    position = position.limit(-this.options.offset, this.max -this.options.offset);

    this.step = this.toStep(position);

    //this.moveKnob = this.knob;
    this.bkg.style.clip = "rect(0px "+  (parseInt(this.toPosition(this.step)) +3) + "px 10px 0px)"  
    //status =this.bkg.style.clip; //Debug
    this.checkStep();
    this.end();
    this.fireEvent('onTick', position);
},

draggedKnob: function(mx){
    var lim = {}; var mi,mx;
    if(mx==null) {
        this.step = this.toStep(this.drag.value.now[this.z]);    
        this.checkStep();
    }else {
        this.maxstep = this.toStep(this.maxdrag.value.now[this.z]); 
        this.checkStep(1);
    }
},
checkStep: function(mx){
    var lim = {}; var mi,mx;
    var limm = {};
    if(mx==null) {if (this.previousChange != this.step){this.previousChange = this.step;}}
    else {if (this.maxPreviousChange != this.maxstep){this.maxPreviousChange = this.maxstep;}}

    if(this.maxknob!=null) {

        mi = - this.options.offset; 
        mx= parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left')) - this.options.offset-4 ;
        //mx= parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left')) - this.options.offset ;
        lim[this.z] = [mi, mx];
        this.drag.options.limit = lim;


        mi = parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left'))-this.options.offset+22; 
        //mi = parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left'))-this.options.offset; 

        mx= this.max - this.options.offset;
        limm[this.z] = [mi, mx];
        this.maxdrag.options.limit = limm; 

        if(this.step < this.maxstep){
            this.fireEvent('onChange', { minpos: this.step, maxpos: this.maxstep });
            //this.clip_l = parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left'));
        }
        else{
            this.fireEvent('onChange', { minpos: this.maxstep, maxpos: this.step });
            //this.clip_l = (parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left')) + 10) ;
        }   
        this.clip_l = parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left')) + 10;
        //var w = Math.abs(parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left')) - parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left'))) + 3; 
        var w = Math.abs(parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left')) - parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left')));
        //if(w > 3) w = w+3;

        var r = parseInt(this.clip_l + w); 
        this.bkg.style.clip = "rect(0px "+  r + "px 10px "+ this.clip_l + "px)"  
        //status =this.bkg.style.clip  + " w= " + w //Debug

    }else {  
        this.fireEvent('onChange', this.step);
        this.bkg.style.clip = "rect(0px "+  (parseInt(this.drag.value.now[this.z]) +3)  + "px 10px 0px)"  

    }
},
end: function(){
    if (this.previousEnd !== this.step || (this.maxknob != null && this.maxPreviousEnd != this.maxstep)) {
        this.previousEnd = this.step;
        if(this.maxknob != null) {
            this.maxPreviousEnd = this.maxstep;
            if(this.step < this.maxstep)
                this.fireEvent('onComplete', { minpos: this.step + '', maxpos: this.maxstep + '' });
            else    
                this.fireEvent('onComplete', { minpos: this.maxstep + '', maxpos: this.step + '' });
        }else{  
            this.fireEvent('onComplete', this.step + '');
        }
    }
},

toStep: function(position){
    return Math.round((position + this.options.offset) / this.max * this.options.steps) + this.options.start;
},

toPosition: function(step){
    return (this.max * step / this.options.steps) - (this.max * this.options.start / this.options.steps) - this.options.offset;
}

});

SliderMoj.implement(new Events);
SliderMoj.implement(new Options);
```

Best regards,
Nemanja

Comment: I found solution for this problem:

Comment: Doubt it, `.bind` is not supported in old IE.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but for me is important ie7, ie8, .... ie11. Currently working good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found solution for this problem.**

The code should look like this:

```
'var SliderMoj = new 
 Class({
options: {
    onChange: Class.empty,
    onComplete: Class.empty,
    onTick: function(pos){
        this.moveKnob.setStyle(this.p, pos);            
    },
    start: 0,
    end: 100,
    offset: 0,
    knobheight: 20,
    knobwidth: 14,
    mode: 'horizontal',
    clip_w:0, 
    clip_l:0,
    isinit:true,
    snap: false,
    range: false,
    numsteps:null
},
initialize: function(el, knob,bkg, options, maxknob) {
    this.setOptions(options);
    this.element = $(el);
    this.knob = $(knob);
    this.previousChange = this.previousEnd = this.step = -1;
    this.bkg = $(bkg);
    if(this.options.steps==null){
        this.options.steps = this.options.end - this.options.start;
    }
    if(maxknob!=null)
        this.maxknob = $(maxknob);
    //else
    //  this.element.addEvent('mousedown',    this.clickedElement.bindWithEvent(this));
    var mod, offset;
    switch(this.options.mode){
        case 'horizontal':
            this.z = 'x';
            this.p = 'left';
            mod = {'x': 'left', 'y': false};
            offset = 'offsetWidth';
            break;
        case 'vertical':
            this.z = 'y';
            this.p = 'top';
            mod = {'x': false, 'y': 'top'};
            offset = 'offsetHeight';
    }
    this.max = this.element[offset] - this.knob[offset] + (this.options.offset * 2);
    this.half = this.knob[offset]/2;
    this.full = this.element[offset] - this.knob[offset] + (this.options.offset * 2);
    this.min = $chk(this.options.range[0]) ? this.options.range[0] : 0;
    this.getPos = this.element['get' + this.p.capitalize()].bind(this.element);
    this.knob.setStyle('position', 'relative').setStyle(this.p, - this.options.offset);

    this.range = this.max - this.min;
    this.steps = this.options.steps || this.full;
    this.stepSize = Math.abs(this.range) / this.steps;
    this.stepWidth = this.stepSize * this.full / Math.abs(this.range) ;


    if(maxknob != null) {
        this.maxPreviousChange = -1;
        this.maxPreviousEnd = -1;
        this.maxstep = this.options.end;
        this.maxknob.setStyle('position', 'relative').setStyle(this.p, + this.max - this.options.offset).setStyle('bottom', this.options.knobheight);
    }
    var lim = {};
    //status = this.z
    lim[this.z] = [- this.options.offset, this.max - this.options.offset];
    //lim[this.z] = [100, this.max - this.options.offset];

    this.drag = new Drag(this.knob, {
        limit: lim,
        modifiers: mod,
        snap: 0,
        onStart: function(){
                this.draggedKnob();
        }.bind(this),
        onDrag: function(){
                this.draggedKnob();
        }.bind(this),
        onComplete: function(){
                this.draggedKnob();
                this.end();
        }.bind(this)
    });
    if(maxknob != null) {  
        this.maxdrag = new Drag(this.maxknob, {
            limit: lim,
            modifiers: mod,
            snap: 0, 
            onStart: function(){
                this.draggedKnob(1);
            }.bind(this),
            onDrag: function(){
                this.draggedKnob(1);
            }.bind(this),
            onComplete: function(){
                this.draggedKnob(1);
                this.end();
            }.bind(this)
        });     
    }

    if (this.options.snap) {
        //this.drag.options.grid = Math.ceil(this.stepWidth);
        this.drag.options.grid = (this.full)/this.options.numsteps ;
        this.drag.options.limit[this.z][1] = this.full;
        //this.drag.options.grid = this.drag.options.grid - (this.knob[offset]/this.options.numsteps);
        status = "GRID - " + this.drag.options.grid  + "  , full = " + this.full// DEBUG

    }
    if (this.options.initialize) this.options.initialize.call(this);
},
setMin: function(stepMin){
    this.step = stepMin.limit(this.options.start, this.options.end);
    this.checkStep();
    this.end();
    this.moveKnob = this.knob;
    this.bkg.style.clip = "rect(0px "+  (parseInt(this.toPosition(this.step)) +3) + "px 10px 0px)";
    status =this.bkg.style.clip + "  vl= " + parseInt(this.toPosition(this.step)) ; //Debug
    this.fireEvent('onTick', this.toPosition(this.step));
    return this;
},
setMax: function(stepMax){
    this.maxstep = stepMax.limit(this.options.start, this.options.end);
    this.checkStep(1);
    this.end();
    this.moveKnob = this.maxknob;
    var w= Math.abs(this.toPosition(this.step)- this.toPosition(this.maxstep)) + 3 ;
    var r = parseInt(this.clip_l + w); 
    this.bkg.style.clip = "rect(0px "+  r + "px 10px "+ this.clip_l + "px)";

    this.fireEvent('onTick', this.toPosition(this.maxstep));
    // For Init Only 
    if(this.options.isinit){
        var lim = {}; var mi,mx;
        mi = - this.options.offset; 
        mx= parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left')) - this.options.offset-4 ;
        lim[this.z] = [mi, mx];
        this.drag.options.limit = lim;
        this.options.isinit = false;
    }
    return this; 
},
clickedElement: function(event){
    var position = event.page[this.z] - this.getPos() - this.half;
    position = position.limit(-this.options.offset, this.max -this.options.offset);

    this.step = this.toStep(position);

    //this.moveKnob = this.knob;
    this.bkg.style.clip = "rect(0px "+  (parseInt(this.toPosition(this.step)) +3) + "px 10px 0px)"  
    //status =this.bkg.style.clip; //Debug
    this.checkStep();
    this.end();
    this.fireEvent('onTick', position);
},

draggedKnob: function(mx){
    var lim = {}; var mi,mx;
    if(mx==null) {
        this.step = this.toStep(this.drag.value.now[this.z]);    
        this.checkStep();
    }else {
        this.maxstep = this.toStep(this.maxdrag.value.now[this.z]); 
        this.checkStep(1);
    }
},
checkStep: function(mx){
    var lim = {}; var mi,mx;
    var limm = {};
    if(mx==null) {if (this.previousChange != this.step){this.previousChange = this.step;}}
    else {if (this.maxPreviousChange != this.maxstep){this.maxPreviousChange = this.maxstep;}}

    if(this.maxknob!=null) {

        mi = - this.options.offset; 
        mx= parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left')) - this.options.offset-4 ;
        //mx= parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left')) - this.options.offset ;
        lim[this.z] = [mi, mx];
        this.drag.options.limit = lim;


        mi = parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left'))-this.options.offset+22; 
        //mi = parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left'))-this.options.offset; 

        mx= this.max - this.options.offset;
        limm[this.z] = [mi, mx];
        this.maxdrag.options.limit = limm; 

        if(this.step < this.maxstep){
            this.fireEvent('onChange', { minpos: this.step, maxpos: this.maxstep });
            //this.clip_l = parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left'));
        }
        else{
            this.fireEvent('onChange', { minpos: this.maxstep, maxpos: this.step });
            //this.clip_l = (parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left')) + 10) ;
        }   
        this.clip_l = parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left')) + 10;
        //var w = Math.abs(parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left')) - parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left'))) + 3; 
        var w = Math.abs(parseInt(this.knob.getStyle('left')) - parseInt(this.maxknob.getStyle('left')));
        //if(w > 3) w = w+3;

        var r = parseInt(this.clip_l + w); 
        this.bkg.style.clip = "rect(0px "+  r + "px 10px "+ this.clip_l + "px)"  
        //status =this.bkg.style.clip  + " w= " + w //Debug

    }else {  
        this.fireEvent('onChange', this.step);
        this.bkg.style.clip = "rect(0px "+  (parseInt(this.drag.value.now[this.z]) +3)  + "px 10px 0px)"  

    }
},
end: function(){
    if (this.previousEnd !== this.step || (this.maxknob != null && this.maxPreviousEnd != this.maxstep)) {
        this.previousEnd = this.step;
        if(this.maxknob != null) {
            this.maxPreviousEnd = this.maxstep;
            if(this.step < this.maxstep)
                this.fireEvent('onComplete', { minpos: this.step + '', maxpos: this.maxstep + '' });
            else    
                this.fireEvent('onComplete', { minpos: this.maxstep + '', maxpos: this.step + '' });
        }else{  
            this.fireEvent('onComplete', this.step + '');
        }
    }
},

toStep: function(position){
    return Math.round((position + this.options.offset) / this.max * this.options.steps) + this.options.start;
},

toPosition: function(step){
    return (this.max * step / this.options.steps) - (this.max *   this.options.start / this.options.steps) - this.options.offset;
}

});'
```

@kiran-rs